# Get images from resources folder on a JAR in a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. When I deploy mi application in a local Tomcat as a war, I'm able to use images from the resources folder by this way:

```
ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:Logo.png")
```

My problem is when I package the applications as a JAR. Seems that is not able to find the images... After some time searching the internet, I tried a few different things, but none have worked so far.

```
Resource resource  = new ClassPathResource("classpath:Logo.png");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
imagePart.attachFile(FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader));
```

Edit:
Project Structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the project structure? If the images are placed in *test/resources/* or *main/resources* folder then the jar will not have any resources from tests or main folder. That could be one possibility.

Comment: Done! The image is located in src/main/resources

Comment: Create a new package under main/java/ and place your image over there. As jar files  will not have files or folders from resources

Comment: Jar files will have only files from "main/java/" folder

Comment: @BhoomikaG I don't think so. Jar file will have the resource folders